# join on two different columns

Tags: sql, join

```
Table 1 people_ID TypePerson
----------------------------
          5525       person1
          6250       person2
          5897       person2
          2584       person1

Table2 person1 person2
----------------------
         5525      5897
         2584      6250
```

I want to join  table1 on two different columns of table2.
Till now i have this:

```
select * 
from table1 join 
     table2 
     on people_ID = person1
```

I know for a fact this is not correct but i have no idea how to proceed.(There are more variables but I can only join on these so i left the other ones out)
Pleas help!

Comment: Join the same table twice with different alias names.

Comment: Please read & act on the edit help, look at your formatted post & see how it has been edited. Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes expected output. "join table1 on two different columns of table2" is not clear. Explain about being stuck--what examples you have seen are like what you want? See hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: Sample data is great, but specify the expected result as well.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score -1):

Try this query

```
Declare @table1 table(people_ID int, TypePerson varchar(100))
insert into @table1(people_ID, TypePerson)
select 5525,'person1' union
select 6250,'person2' union
select 5897,'person2' union
select 2584,'person1' 

declare @table2 table(person1 int, person2 int)
insert into @table2(Person1, person2)
select  5525,      5897 union
select  2584,      6250 

select * from @table1
select * from @table2

select *
from @table2 t1
left join @table1 t2a on 
t2a.people_ID= t1.person1
left join @table1 t2b on 
t2b.people_ID= t1.person2
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using `LEFT JOIN`. If you just use `JOIN`, it performs an `INNER JOIN` by default, which would cause you to get no return value if your ID does not exist in both columns of the 2nd table.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2a ON t1.people_ID = t2.person1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2b ON t1.people_ID = t2.person2
```